# Search for multiple verbs except if the last one is followed by a comma

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm searching a corpus for clusters of multiple verbs using a regular expression. All the words are tagged for word class so any sentence may look like this:

```
I.prn love.vrb dogs.noun
```

I want my regular expressions to match all instances of 2 or more verbs occurring after each other, except if the last verb is followed by a comma. See two instances of preferred matches below:

```
I.prn have.vrb been.vrb using.vrb regex.noun # match = have.vrb been.vrb using.vrb
```

---

```
the.det functions.noun I.prn have.vrb been.vrb using.vrb, .... # match = NULL
```

My current regular expression looks like this (it's not really optimal I feel):

```
((([a-z])+(\.vrb))(([a-z]|([ ]{1,}))+(\.vrb)){1,})(?!,)
```

It checks for any word followed by.vrb and then checks for a minimum of 1 other instance of a word ending in .vrb with any number of spaces in between. I want it to do this except if there is a comma at the end, but my current expression gives me the following match for the previous sentence (which is not what i want):

```
the.det functions.noun I.prn have.vrb been.vrb using.vrb, .... # match = have.vrb been.vrb
```

Is there any way to alter my regular expression to yield no match in the case of the above sentence (i.e the last verb is followed by a comma)? I hope I explained my problem well!

Comment: Try: `([a-z]+\.vrb\s){2,}`, is this what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved file `text.txt` containing the following text:

```
I.prn have.vrb been.vrb using.vrb regex.noun
the.det functions.noun I.prn have.vrb been.vrb using.vrb,
the.det programs.noun I.prn have.vrb been.vrb writing.vrb
```

Then I ran the following piped command:

```
egrep -o '(([A-Za-z]+\.vrb[ ]*)+[A-Za-z]+\.[^v][^r][^b])|(([A-Za-z]+\.vrb[ ]*)+)$' text.txt | egrep -o '([A-Za-z]+\.vrb[ ]*)+'
```

and got the following output (as desired):

```
have.vrb been.vrb using.vrb 
have.vrb been.vrb writing.vrb
```

The first regexp gets the chain of verbs (space-separated only) AND the following word (a non-verb) OR it gets the chain of verbs (space-separated only) followed by eol.

The second regexp filters out the non-verb word, if it's there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @L.Suurmeijer and with pcre regex this could look like [`\b([a-z]+\.vrb)(?: +(?1))++(?!,)`](https://regex101.com/r/njV52A/1) (@JulianNeuer, add to answer if you want).

Comment: Edited my previous answer in order to provide a solution. Thanks @bobblebubble

Comment: Thank you, helped me a bunch!